# Prove that OD is a the angle bisector of the angle BOC.

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a non-isosceles triangle and $I$ be the intersection of the three internal angle bisectors. Let $D$ be a point of $BC$ such that $ID \perp BC$ and $O$ be a point on $AD$ such that $IO \perp AD$. 
Prove that $OD$ is a the angle bisector of $\angle BOC$.

[image: diagram]

Comment: Angle bisector of which angle?

Comment: mathh: BOC.
You, Kim Jong Un do it this problem, please.

Comment: @DoHoaiPhuong: I can't do much until I get home tonight. By then, someone will most likely have helped you already. Cheers.

Comment: Already 18 hours. Kim Jong Un,Have you solved this problem yet? you solved this problem yet?

Comment: @DoHoaiPhuong: Your impatient demands are rude, and unlikely to spur interest in solving your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This problem can be solve using the knowledge about Harmonic conjugate and polar. Notice me if you need those information. 
[image]

hope this still can help.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks you for your solution. #Samara
My solution:
[image]

[image]